# No sé cómo recargar datatable con filtro personal

Tags: html, jquery

Estoy realizando un datatable mediante un filtro porque no quiero que me cargue 3.500 registros en un datatable al iniciar, es por eso que pongo una caja de texto para realizar la búsqueda de N personas, me realiza bien la búsqueda y me devuelve 4 registros en este caso como se ve en la imagen, pero no logro que me recargue el datatable.

Pongo parte del código para que vean qué es lo que hago y agrego la imagen para que vean que me devuelve los 4 registros.

La verdad no sé cómo refrescar el datatable después de una nueva búsqueda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
 $(".btn-buscar-agente").on('click', function() {

            if ($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable('#tablaAgentes')) {
                $('#tablaAgentes').dataTable().fnDestroy();
            }

            var datos = {
                "accion": 'buscarAgente_X_Apellido',
                "apellido": $("#txtApellidoBuscar").val().trim()
            };

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax/agentes.ajax2.php",
                data: datos,
                success: function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    } // Success End
                    ,
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, error) {
                    console.log(xhr.statusText);
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    console.log(error);
                }// Error End
            }); //AJAX End
        });
```

Comment: no te esta recargando por que el ajax esta cargando los datos a la consola

Comment: Si lo puse para saber si me traía datos. Pero no se como recargar el datatable cada vez que realizo un nuevo filtro?

Comment: debes entonces repasar el manual https://datatables.net/manual/ajax

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucioné de la siguiente manera por si a alguien le interesa o le sirve. De esta manera evito cargar 3.500 registros e inicio mi datatable vacio y despues con un filtro personal cargo los registros que me interesan.

```js
$("#btnBuscarAgente").on('click', function() {
    var datos = {
        "accion": 'buscarAgente_X_Apellido',
        "apellido": $("#txtApellidoBuscar").val().trim()
    };
                
    jQuery.ajax({
        destroy: true,
        processing: true,
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/agentes.ajax2.php",
        data: datos,
        dataType: '',
        success: function(data) {
                var table = $('#tablaAgentes').DataTable();
                table.clear().rows.add(data).draw();
                console.log(data);
            } // Success End
            ,
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, error) {
            console.log(xhr.statusText);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(error);
        } // Error End
    }); //AJAX End
});
```

```html
var table = $('#tablaAgentes').DataTable({
            "language": {
                "processing": "Procesando...",
                "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                "zeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
                "emptyTable": "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
                "infoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
                "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                "search": "Buscar Agente:",
                "infoThousands": ",",
                "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                "paginate": {
                    "first": "Primero",
                    "last": "Último",
                    "next": "Siguiente",
                    "previous": "Anterior"
                },
                "info": "Mostrando ( _START_ a _END_ ) de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
            },
        });
```